# ruby-inotify example?

Tags: ruby, inotify

I'm looking for a simple, concise example of using the [inotify](http://dinhe.net/~aredridel/projects/ruby/ruby-inotify-0.0.2/doc/) gem to detect a change to a directory.

It lacks examples.

Comment: Did you find anymore examples ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in [examples/watcher.rb](https://github.com/aredridel/ruby-inotify/blob/master/examples/watcher.rb).
That link is to aredridel's repo, since it looks like you linked to aredridel's docs, and aredridel is the one who wrote the example.

Answer (score 0):

One of my projects I have used `ruby-inotify` for monitoring file creation under specific folder using following code

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rb-inotify'

# observe indicate folder, trigger event after
module ObserveFiles
  def self.observe
    watcher = INotify::Notifier.new
    directory = CONFIG['xml_folder'] # folder that want to watch
    watcher.watch(directory, :create) do |event|
      # do your work where 
      # here, event.name is created file name
      # event.absolute_name file absolute path
    end
    watcher.run
  end
end
```

Use this code like

`ObserveFiles.observe`

Hope this will help someone.