# Is it possible to "keep track" of a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a library for testing purposes that spawns a large amount of dummy files that will most likely be moved around and renamed. I would like my library to keep track of the files so that I can remove them (or reset them) after testing is complete. I am also going to store changes made to these files for logging purposes.

Is it possible to detect when a File or Directory moves, or is renamed and detect where they were moved to in the scope of a script?

**Bonus**
Is it possible to detect when a new file is created in a specific directory(non-recursive)?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? This sort of thing is very OS-specific (and largely unrelated to your choice of programming language), if it is possible at all.

Comment: Linux - Ubuntu 12.04 specifically

Comment: The best I can imagine is just using logger to log every time you move and rename a file and then parsing that.

Comment: also, I'm ok with not detecting direct system calls such as `\`mkdir\``. If there was a way to keep track of when something like Dir.mkdir is called within the script(or possibly lower level methods Dir uses) that would be nice

Comment: Why not just log everytime you use `mkdir`?

Comment: The system call or `Dir.mkdir`? If the later I'm currently looking into creating system hooks on the ruby core methods that change files such as `IO` `File` and `Dir`. I'm just trying to put together a list of methods to figure out how much hooking that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [inotify](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facility in Linux can probably help with what you want to do. I don't know whether there is specifically a Ruby interface to inotify, though (however, a quick search turned up [ruby-inotify example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424212/ruby-inotify-example)).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure I've had to included it in a gem file before. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: The gem `rb-inotify` should do this. I had to include this dependency for guard.

Comment: ...also guard as a good list of gems for other operating systems as well in [their docs](https://github.com/guard/guard#efficient-filesystem-handling)